# Postgresql: Array append with multi-dimension

Tags: postgresql

I have following problem with adding to multi-dim arrays:

```
create table dummy (id int, list int[][]);  -- ok

insert into dummy (id, list) values (1, ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2]]); -- ok

update dummy set list = array_append(list, ARRAY[2, 3]) where id = 1;

-- error: function array_append(integer[], integer[]) does not exist
```

any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok this worked:

```
update dummy set list = list || ARRAY[2, 3] where id = 1;
```

although still not sure why array append did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to array_append() should be element. But you are providing array.

Syntax:
array_append(anyarray, anyelement)

ex. array_append(list,2) should work